# In Scala what is the easiest way to parse json and map to objects?

Tags: scala, lift, lift-json

I'm looking for a super simple way to take a big JSON fragment, that is a long list with a bunch of big objects in it, and parse it, then pick out the same few values from each object and then map into a case class.

I have tried pretty hard to get lift-json (2.5) working for me, but I'm having trouble cleanly dealing with checking if a key is present, and if so, then map the whole object, but if not, then skip it.

I absolutely do not understand this syntax for Lift-JSON one bit:

```
case class Car(make: String, model: String)

...

val parsed = parse(jsonFragment)
val JArray(cars) = parsed / "cars"

val carList = new MutableList[Car]
for (car <- cars) {
    val JString(model) = car / "model"
    val JString(make) = car / "make"

    // i want to check if they both exist here, and if so 
    // then add to carList
    carList += car
}
```

What on earth is that construct that makes it look like a case class is being created left of the assignment operator?  I'm talking about the "JString" part.
Also how is it supposed to cope with the situation where a key is missing?

Can someone please explain to me what the right way to do this is? 
And if I have nested values I'm looking for, I just want to skip the whole object and go on to try to map the next one.

Is there something more straightforward for this than Lift-JSON?

Would using **extractOpt** help?

I have looked at this a lot:
https://github.com/lift/framework/tree/master/core/json

and it's still not particularly clear to me.

Help is **very much** appreciated!!!!!

Comment: I am a little confused - are you looking to pick out a few values for each item to populate your case classes with that subset, or are you looking to use those few values to perform some tests on and then populate the case object with the entire record?

Comment: @jcern I'm just trying to pick out a few values and populate case classes with subset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are only looking to extract certain fields, you are on the right track.  This modified version of your `for-comprehension` will loop through your car structure, extract the make and model and only yield your case class if both items exist:

```
for{ 
  car <- cars
  model <- (car \ "model").extractOpt[String]
  make <- (car \ "make").extractOpt[String]
} yield Car(make, model)
```

You would add additional required fields the same way. If you want to also utilize optional parameters, let's say `color` - then you can call that in your yield section and the for comprehension won't unbox them:

```
for{ 
  car <- cars
  model <- (car \ "model").extractOpt[String]
  make <- (car \ "make").extractOpt[String]
} yield Car(make, model, (car \ "color").extractOpt[String])
```

In both cases you will get back a `List` of `Car` case classes.

Comment: extractOpt does not work for me... i get "could not find implicit value for parameter formats: net.liftweb.json.Formats"  anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Ah, I had not added "implicit val formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats"

Answer (score 2):

The weird looking assignment is *pattern-matching* used on `val` declaration.

When you see

```
val JArray(cars) = parsed / "cars"
```

it extracts from the parsed json the subtree of `"cars"` objects and matches the resulting value with the *extractor pattern* `JArrays(cars)`.
That is to say that the value is expected to be in the form of a constructor `JArrays(something)` and the `something` is bound to the `cars` variable name.

It works pretty much the same as you're probably familiar with case classes, like `Options`, e.g.

```
//define a value with a class that can pattern match
val option = Some(1)
//do the matching on val assignment
val Some(number) = option
//use the extracted binding as a variable
println(number)
```

The following assignments are exactly the same stuff

```
//pattern match on a JSon String whose inner value is assigned to "model"
val JString(model) = car / "model"
//pattern match on a JSon String whose inner value is assigned to "make"
val JString(make) = car / "make"
```

---

### References

The JSON types (e.g. `JValue, JString, JDouble`) are defined as aliases within the `net.liftweb.json` object [here](https://github.com/lift/lift/blob/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/json/package.scala).

The aliases in turn point to corresponding inner *case classes* within the `net.liftweb.json.JsonAST` object, found [here](https://github.com/lift/lift/blob/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/json/JsonAST.scala)

The case classes have an `unapply` method for free, which lets you do the *pattern-matching* as explained in the above answer.

Comment: can you explain what you mean unapply for free?  Does this mean that all case classes will reverse the effect of the apply function if the case class is on the left side of the assignment operator?

Comment: It means that case classes generate a lot of boilerplate for you, and one of them is the unapply method that is used by pattern matching. And you can do pattern matching in the val statement (it will give a runtime error if it doesn't match). So you can do: case class C(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int); val x = C(1, 2, 3); val C(a, b, _) = x; assert(a == 1)

Comment: +1 thanks I appreciate the explanation, it was very helpful to me.  (And of course +1 and thanks for your original answer too!)

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work for you:

```
case class UserInfo(
        name: String,
        firstName: Option[String],
        lastName: Option[String],
        smiles: Boolean
        )

val jValue: JValue
val extractedUserInfoClass: Option[UserInfo] = jValue.extractOpt[UserInfo]

val jsonArray: JArray
val listOfUserInfos: List[Option[UserInfo]] = jsonArray.arr.map(_.extractOpt[UserInfo])
```

I expect `jValue` to have `smiles` and `name` -- otherwise extracting will fail.

I don't expect `jValue` to necessarily have `firstName` and `lastName` -- so I write `Option[T]` in the case class.